# String input into int array -- C

Tags: c, arrays, hex

I'm trying to write a program that will convert a floating point number into its IEEE 754 single representation and vice versa. I'm stuck on how to take the input, which will be in the form "0xABCD123" or "2.83234e-2" (with the hex representation always preceded by "0x"), and take each element and put it into a char array.

For example, the input "0xABCD123" will be in a char array of size 10. I will remove the "0" and "x" elements, and then go through each element individually and convert into floating point from there with the use of a for loop.

Getting the argument from the command line is simple enough I think. The argument is stored in `argv[1]`, then I save that into an initialized string variable called `input`. The problem is taking `input` and putting each element into a character array. The second problem is determining the length of the array if the input is not in IEEE format. I haven't found a function that determines the length of a string (removing decimals points and account for the 'e').

Also, a couple questions: Does C automatically recognize the "e-2" part of an input and translate that into the actual number? Is there some command I can use to do that?

How would type casting work here? If the input was "2.83234e3", and I wanted to save the part to the left of the decimal point as an int (because that would be easier to translate), and then the left as an int as well, how would I split up the number through type casting? Would it be something like `input = (int)left;`?

Comment: How many times do you want to keep moving the input data from one array to another?

Comment: Once. If the input is in hex form, it needs to be moved to an array with the proper length, so that I can translate each element into it's floating point equivalent, and then add them all up to produce a final number. If the input is in floating point, it needs to be moved into an array as well.

Comment: You said move it from the array `argv[1]` to the array `input` and then into yet another array.

Comment: Well isn't the argument from the command line automatically stored into `argv[1]`? The variable `input` isn't an array. It's a string. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Both `argv[1]` and `input` (a string) are arrays. Why not just examine each element of `argv[1]`, with a loop such as `for(j=0; j<strlen(argv[1]); j++) printf("%c",argv[1][j]);`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with putting the two brackets after the array name. What does that do exactly?

Comment: It accesses a 2-D array. `argv[]` is an array of string pointers. Each string is an array. `argv[1][3]` access the 4th character of the 2nd program argument.